# Changing Woocommerce first active tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I want to change the first tab in the tabs section at the bottom of the Woocommerce product screen.

I want to move the 3rd row, which I shown as an example in the picture, to the first row and I want it to be active tab.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szLgY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code ([from here](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/change-product-tabs-order.html)):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'misha_change_tabs_order', 98 );

function misha_change_tabs_order( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 5;

    return $tabs;

}
```

You maybe need to find out the name of your tab.